# Getting over the hump

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This isn't really a question. I was about to post it in chat but figured not many people would see it there.

Recently I've noticed several questions being closed by 5 regular close voters, without mod involvement.  This is awesome!  I think this is the big indicator of the site becoming "self-sustainable", for lack of a better phrase.

Thanks to everyone who have been so committed to the site!

Comment: As one of the non-mods regularly close-voting and editing, I've been noticing the same, we're finally starting to have a [proper middle class](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/578/you-need-the-bourgeois-blues)! Does this mean that we're growing up?

Comment: I'm very excited to see this also :)

Comment: Happy to contribute in any way I can :)